# Drupal UC "Quoting / Estimate" error

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, quotes

I was playing around with Drupal UC and installed a module called "Quoting / Estimate"
(http://drupal.org/project/quoting), I tried to run it and got this error:

******warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'quoting_quote_clear_page' was given in /home/ergospec/public_html/d/includes/menu.inc on line 348******

Has anyone run into this problem?

Second question: anyone know of a good quotation module (where customer can request a price quote, not the brackets)? It doesn't have to be in Drupal.

Any help is appreciated.

Murtez

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific example of a pretty general problem when dealing with code. You have an error somewhere, and the error message points you to a line of code that is not super helpful. `menu.inc` is a file in Drupal core, so it is not likely that the bug is there. There are a few things to try:

- Have you verified that the error only appears when the Quoting/Estimate module is enabled? If not, disable the module and see if the error disappears.
- Have you looked in the issue queue of the module? Often others have encountered your specific problem. You can see if a patch has been created, or create a new issue to report the bug.
- Have you looked at the code the error message points you to? It looks like this:

```
return call_user_func_array($router_item['page_callback'], $router_item['page_arguments']);
```

It is basically calling a callback function as specified in `quoting_menu` to generate the page you are trying to get to. The error suggests that the function it is trying to call, `quoting_quote_clear_page` does not exist. Have you checked the module to see if that function exists?